# ANTLR4 grammar for tags substitution

Tags: template, grammar, antlr

I want your criticism of the following ANTLR4 grammar intended for use in templating engine of sorts. Its task is to look through (presumably rather short) potentially multiline piece of plaintext, find all the tags of the form `<tagname>` and substitute their values from a data source. These are requirements that I can not change:

- Plaintext can contain anything (including `<`, `>` and line ends).
- Tag name can contain anything except line end.
- To satisfy the above two requirements `<`, `>` and `\` can be escaped with `\` like so `this \<is not\> a tag`.
- Input text can contain mixed end-of-lines: `CR`, `CR`-`LF` and `LF`. The grammar should detect them so that all of them can be replaced with system specific variant.
- The parser can fail to find tags in some corner cases but it can not produce any errors. Any input text should be valid.

TagsLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar TagsLexer;

TAGSTART   : '<'-> pushMode(tagMode) ;
// more lexer command is used to glue
// escape symbol to the following
// symbol that it gives special meaning to
// so that we don't have to handle escaping
// in parser.
ESCAPE: '\\' -> more, pushMode(plaintextEscapeMode);
TEXT : ~('<'|'\\'|'\r'|'\n')+;
CR: '\r';
LF: '\n';

mode plaintextEscapeMode ;
ESCAPED_TAGSTART: '<' -> popMode ;
ESCAPED_TAGEND: '>' -> popMode ;
ESCAPED_ESCAPE: '\\' -> popMode ;
ESCAPED_TEXT : ~('<'|'>'|'\\'|'\r'|'\n') -> type(TEXT), popMode;
// Tag substitution does not require 
// special treatment of escaped end of lines
// (as opposed to ends of lines not preceded 
// by '\' symbol).
// But there seems to be no elegant way 
// of reversing 'more' lexer command 
// (see ESCAPE rule above)
ESCAPED_CR: '\r' -> popMode;
ESCAPED_LF: '\n' -> popMode;

mode tagMode ;
TAGEND : '>' -> popMode ;
TAG_ESCAPE: '\\' -> more, pushMode(tagEscapeMode);
TAGNAME : ~('>'|'\\'|'\r'|'\n')+ -> type(TEXT);
TAG_CR: '\r' -> type(CR), popMode;
TAG_LF: '\n' -> type(LF), popMode;

mode tagEscapeMode ;
TAG_ESCAPED_TAGSTART: '<' -> type(ESCAPED_TAGSTART), popMode ;
TAG_ESCAPED_TAGEND: '>' -> type(ESCAPED_TAGEND), popMode ;
TAG_ESCAPED_ESCAPE: '\\' -> type(ESCAPED_ESCAPE), popMode ;
TAG_ESCAPED_TAGNAME : ~('<'|'>'|'\\'|'\r'|'\n') -> type(TEXT), popMode;
TAG_ESCAPED_CR: '\r' -> type(ESCAPED_CR), popMode;
TAG_ESCAPED_LF: '\n' -> type(ESCAPED_LF), popMode;
```

TagsParser.g4

```
parser grammar TagsParser;

options { tokenVocab=TagsLexer; }

eol: CR | CR LF | LF;
escaped_eol: ESCAPED_CR | ESCAPED_CR LF | ESCAPED_LF;

escaped_symbol: ESCAPED_TAGSTART 
              | ESCAPED_TAGEND 
              | ESCAPED_ESCAPE;

tag_name: (TEXT 
        | escaped_symbol )+;

tag: TAGSTART tag_name TAGEND;

message_line: 
            // line can include unmatched 
            // tag end symbols
            ((TEXT 
            | escaped_symbol 
            | TAGEND)*
            TAGEND )?
            // line can include tags
            // and plaintext
            (TEXT 
            | escaped_symbol 
            | tag)*
            // line can include unmatched
            // tag start symbols
            (TAGSTART
            (TEXT 
            | escaped_symbol 
            | TAGSTART)*)?;

message: message_line 
         ((eol|escaped_eol) message_line)* 
         (eol|escaped_eol)?;
```

Usage example:
[image: a parse tree]

The grammar and some usage examples are [in GitLab](https://gitlab.com/fedorkotov/antlr-tag-substitution-parser-grammar/-/tree/cc1089bbd689aebe0006a6fd7ec8eeec2c809beb).